# Allround Automations' PL/SQL developer doesn't display null value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

There is a null value for a column in Oracle database. The column datatype is long.

In Allround Automations' PL/SQL developer, the null value is not getting displayed. The datatype long is getting displayed.

In Oracle SQL developer, null value is getting displayed.

How to get the null value to be displayed in the Allround Automations' PL/SQL developer?

```
CREATE TABLE test1234567
( customer_id number(10) not null,
  customer_name long,
  city varchar2(50)
);
/
select * from test1234567;
/
insert into test1234567
(customer_id, customer_name,city)
values
(123,'mohanrajkumar','mumbai');
/
insert into test1234567
(customer_id, city)
values
(134,'chennai');
/
```

if I query the same in oracle sql developer, everything is working fine.

But in pl / sql developer, even the value "mohanrajkumar" is not getting displayed. The datatype long is getting displayed.

Comment: Doesn't clicking the little button right next to the `<long>` text - I think it's maybe an ellipsis but it's been a while - show you an individual value? Same for CLOB, BLOB etc. The large values are only fetched when actually needed, I don't think you can change that. (I was going to ask why you're still using longs as they've been deprecated for so long, ut the question applies to other types too).

Comment: @AlexPoole ya as you said, I even tried to use the clob and blob datatype. It is giving the same results. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can highlight null values with another color under *Preferences -> Window Types -> SQL Window*

[image: pl/sql-developer screenshot]

Comment: the cell is getting highlighted as a null value with different color, but why, even the actual value is not getting reflected. let me edit my answer with few example

Comment: Ok, that is not because of the `null` value. Possibly large Datatypes like `long` or `clob` don't get dsiplayed in pl/sql developer out of the box and i don't know if it's possible. If just for debugging you could do a workarround by converting to `varchar2`. If you still can you should avoid using `long` columns anyway because that datatype is deprecated.